# Growisofs renaming files

Tags: rename, iso, dvd, recording

I was trying to copy several files to a dvd with growisofs. The command I use it is:

```
growisofs -Z /dev/dvd -R -J  /media/34GB/tmp/
```

But when I send it to command line, I receive this message

> I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)

and then countless messages like these for many of my files.

> Using F1_SC000.JPG;1 for  /media/34GB/tmp/imagens/paper doll ultimos/F1-SCAN1194.JPG (F1-SCAN1189.JPG)

How can I avoid these renaming?

I made a full record, and to my surprise, the final file names are correct, despite the renaming messages. Why these messages appeared then?

Answer (score 1):

It is talking about the underlying [ISO 9660 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660), which is limited to names like `F1_SC000.JPG;1`. You see the "proper" name when mounted because you are using an extension, either [TRANS.TBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRANS.TBL), [Rock Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Ridge_Interchange_Protocol), or [Joliet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joliet_(file_system)).